# Cannot delete created excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have created an excel table. However, I now want to delete or change it because my range changed.

However I can't delete it in the excel `Name Manager`:

[image]

Any suggestion why I cannot delete it?

Would appreciate your answer!

Comment: How about delete it as a range? Look for it in your sheet (it should be in Sheet 'RawData' and you delete manually from there.

Comment: @Jerry Thx for your answer! What do you exactly mean by `deleting it as a range`.

Comment: I meant like selecting the table range from A2 to J something (I can't see the whole range) and then press delete (or to delete it completely, `Ctrl`+`-`.

Comment: Select headers, right click the cells and select Remove Columns

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Highlight all of the cells in the table (and only those cells) then click the Convert to Range button in the Table Tools/Design tab (screenshot below).

Now that this data is no longer grouped as a table, it will appear in the Name Manager as separate columns/rows (depending on how you defined the range) with the delete button no longer greyed out.

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm 

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, in Excel 2010 (Windows), you cannot delete a table using the Names Manager. Your only option here is to pick any cell or select the existing table name (eg Table1, Table2, Table3, etc.) and convert the table back to a range. One you have done this, the table will disappear from the names manager. Then you can go ahead and create a new table.

Answer (score 0):

If the Tools features are not enabled, check to see if there are two (or more) tables on the same tab.  Excel will disable the ability to delete a column if there is more than one table, but you can delete the cells in each table one at a time.